# Need help validating my database through throw statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewAnimal (
 @name varchar(100),
 @owner int,
 @breed int,
 @color varchar(50),
 @birthDate datetime,
 @appointmentDate datetime,
 @vetID int = NULL
 ) AS BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 
--Validate

IF EXISTS (SELECT *FROM Animals WHERE Name = @name AND OwnerID = @owner)
THROW 50001, 'Animal with the same name and owner already exists', 1;

IF @appointmentDate < @birthDate
THROW 50001, 'Invalid appointmentDate', 1;

DECLARE @animalID int
SET @animalID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Animals (Name, OwnerID, BreedID, Color, BirthDate)
VALUES (@name, @owner, @breed, @color, @birthDate)

INSERT INTO Appointments (AnimalID, AppointmentDate, VetID, Reason)
VALUES (@animalID, @appointmentDate, @vetID, 'Initial Appointment')

RETURN(SELECT @animalID, @appointmentDate, @vetID)
END
GO
```

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddNewAnimal, Line 28 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

The procedure should do the following validation.
The animal/owner combination is unique.
The appointment date is later than the birth date.

I think I'm having trouble with the validation part the most, perhaps my syntax is off but I don't understand what I need to do in order to fix it

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL and SQLite when you're using SQL Server?

Comment: Your precondition checks should be in the same `TRANSACTION` as your DML - otherwise it won't work when used concurrently.

Comment: On Microsoft SQL Server the return code from a stored procedure is a single, scalar, `INT` value. i.e.: you cannot specify a result set in a `RETURN` statement.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Why are you checking if the row already exists with an `EXISTS` and then `THROW`ing an error? Why not just create a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT`/`INDEX` on the column(s) if they need to be unique?

Comment: *If* you *must* do this logic in the procedure, at least `THROW` different error numbers; using the same error number for *completely* different problems is a poor idea.

Comment: *Finally* `DECLARE @animalID int
SET @animalID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is just going to assign `NULL`; you've not `INSERT`ed anything. What are you expecting `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to assign exactly?

Comment: @ThomA I've haven't encountered unique constraint or check constraint within a validating statement, so I wasn't sure how to phrase it. would I create the constraints before the if throw statements? or inside?

Comment: *"would I create the constraints before the if throw statements?"* You wouldn't `THROW` at all, the `CONSTRAINT` is created on the table, and then the data engine automatically throws an error when you try to `INSERT`/`UPDATE` a row that breaks that constraint.

Comment: @ThomA I understand that however we want to create our own error messages to appear whenever a constraint is violated.

Comment: @ThomA I'm sorry to bother you again, while testing out the procedure with an Exec statement I received an error because breedId is a foreign key and therefore conflicts with  the insert statement. what can I do to get around that constraint?

Comment: Ensure you `INSERT`/`UPDATE` with a valid value, @mackodanacko .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's several problems with your procedure here, which I'm going to list out:

1. The check on whether the row exists shouldn't be procedure logic; use a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT`/`INDEX` for this.
2. Don't use the same error number for 2 completely different errors.
3. You should really use a more meaningful error message that "Invalid appointmentDate".
4. You assign the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to the variable `@animalID` prior to *any* `INSERT`s; this means that the value assigned will always be `NULL`; which will likely cause an error due to `AnimalID` being assigned `NULL` in your second `INSERT`.
5. `RETURN` returns an `int`, not a tuple, and is designed to denote the *success* of a procedure; `0` for success anything else for failure.
   Likely what you *really* want here is an `OUTPUT` parameter to return the value of `@AnimalID` to the calling application, as "returning" `@appointmentDate` and `@vetID` doesn't make much sense when the application passed those values (so it knows them).
6. You have no transaction or rolling back for your batch, which means that if the first `INSERT` works and the second fails, the first `INSERT` would still occur.

The `UNIQUE` constraint for your table should like look something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Animals ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Animals_NameOwner UNIQUE (Name,OwnerID);
```

Then you can create your procedure, with the validation on the dates and an `OUTPUT` parameter for the animal's ID. I also use `XACT_ABORT` and a transaction to ensure that either *both* `INSERT` statements occur or neither; if the latter `INSERT` fails the transaction is implicitly rolled back:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddNewAnimal @name varchar(100),
                                  @owner int,
                                  @breed int,
                                  @color varchar(50),
                                  @birthDate datetime,
                                  @appointmentDate datetime,
                                  @vetID int = NULL,
                                  @animalID int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --As BirthDate and AppointmentDate are in different tables, we do need a check here.
    IF @appointmentDate < @birthDate
        THROW 50002, N'An error occured in the procedure ''dbo.AddNewAnimal''. The value of the parameter ''@appointmentDate'' cannot be prior to the value of the parameter ''@birthDate''.', 16;

    INSERT INTO dbo.Animals (Name,
                             OwnerID,
                             BreedID,
                             Color,
                             BirthDate)
    VALUES (@name, @owner, @breed, @color, @birthDate);

    SET @animalID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dbo.Appointments (AnimalID,
                                  AppointmentDate,
                                  VetID,
                                  Reason)
    VALUES (@animalID, @appointmentDate, @vetID, 'Initial Appointment');

    COMMIT;
END;
```

<sub>The syntax is checked for the above, but untested, as the question lacks sample DDL for the tables involved</sub>